# How to treat special values as NULLs in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I currently am trying to rewrite a WHERE clause.

```
WHERE (ISNULL(SIDE1,'')<>'' or ISNULL(SIDE2,'')<>'')
```

So if SIDE1 or SIDE2 is null, nothing is selected.

I'd like to also include the WHERE clause evaluating a string. Occasionally, SIDE1 and SIDE2 can contain a value of "other." I'd like to treat that the same way as the above statement. So if SIDE1 or SIDE2 is null and if SIDE1 or SIDE2 contains the value "other."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `WHERE NOT (side1 IS NULL OR side2 IS NULL)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if SIDE1 or SIDE2 is null, nothing is selected.

That's not what the condition says: `OR` in the `WHERE` clause means that nothing is selected when SIDE1 *and* SIDE2 are both null; otherwise, one of the `<>` evaluates to `true`, making the overall `OR` condition `true` as well.

If you would like to treat `'other'` the same way that you treat `null`, you can use `in` condition, like this:

```
WHERE (NOT ISNULL(SIDE1,'') IN ('', 'other')) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear about how the logic is supposed to work, but maybe something like this:

```
WHERE
(!ISNULL(SIDE1) OR !ISNULL(SIDE2))
OR
(SIDE1 != 'other' OR SIDE2 != 'other')
```

Which will return the row if one of SIDE1 or SIDE2 is neither blank nor 'other'

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the DBMS being used, using `ISNULL` on a `WHERE` clause will probably have a drop in performance.

So, you should simply use this, if you are only worried about avoiding `NULL` values:

```
WHERE
    SIDE1 IS NOT NULL AND SIDE2 IS NOT NULL.
```

But then you say you want to treat the "other" value as `NULL`. In that case, why not just do this instead:

```
WHERE
    SIDE1 IS NOT NULL AND SIDE2 IS NOT NULL
    AND SIDE1 <> 'other' AND SIDE2 <> 'other'
```

Yeah, I know. Pretty boring, isn't it? There is no fun when we stop using those clever functions, like `ISNULL`, `NULLIF`, `COALESCE` and so on...

But DBMS's are like paying taxes: we are probably safer when we avoid using clever tricks. It is harder (and, depending on the actual DBMS, even impossible) to index functional calls. That means if we use `ISNULL` on a `WHERE` clause, we are most probably getting full scans on our queries.

So, as a rule of thumb, if you can avoid using a function call on a `WHERE` clause, just do it. Because it is not just better to the DBMS engine, it is also clearer to most humans beings too...

**Edit**

But, of course, if you *really* insist in being clever, one possible answer is

```
WHERE NULLIF(SIDE1, 'other') IS NOT NULL AND NULLIF(SIDE2, 'other') IS NOT NULL
```

or even

```
WHERE COALESCE(NULLIF(SIDE1, 'other'), NULLIF(SIDE2, 'other')) IS NOT NULL
```

Which would work on both Oracle and MS SQL Server databases (and maybe others).